# react-native unable to push recent version of ios code to simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building a react-native application that should work in both the Android simulator and the iOS simulator.  I've been developing primarily on my Windows machine, and I would use command prompt `react-native run-android` to see my changes in an Android simulator.  Once in a while, I would go to my mac mini, do a `git pull origin master`, and then run `react-native run-ios` to see my changes in an iOS simulator.

Everything has been working fine until a few days ago.  Now when I'm on my mac mini, the following will happen:

- if I run `react-native run-android` from my terminal, I see my latest react-native changes in the android simulator, which is perfect
- if I run `react-native run-ios` from my terminal, I see an EARLIER/OLDER version of my react-native changes of the ios simulator.  This is NOT what I want.  I want my ios simulator to show my latest changes the way a developer would expect.  I tried typing garbage, syntax errors, deleting files in my react-native project to see if the compiler will respect these errors and fail, but it does not.  The `react-native run-ios` command ignores my clearly broken project and continues to build the same earlier version of my react-native project and puts it in the ios simulator.  I tried deleting the project, and doing a fresh new git pull, but still the same issue occurs and simulator shows the same earlier version of my project.

Why won't my `react-native run-ios` command build the latest version of my react-native code and put it in the ios simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a workaround.

I started a completely new react-native project with the `react-native init <sameprojectnameasmybrokenproject>`.  Then I copied all my react components and project files (The ones that I created, and not the stuff that react creates boiler templates for) and my package.json file from my broken project to my new project.  Then I ran `react-native run-ios` to make sure this new project works fine.

---

EDIT

I also copied these four files from my new project into my broken project, and it got the broken project to show the latest build versions again.

- ios/nutriag.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
- ios/nutriag.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschema/nutriag.xcscheme
- ios/nutriag/AppDelegate.m
- ios/nutriag/Info.plist

So something about these four files was broken in my broken project.